# how to test object equality using xcttest?

Tags: objective-c, xctest

My method returns a NSNumber* and I want to unit test this method. Since my actual return value is NSNumber*, I create a new expected value of NSNumber*, but it fails. Here is the code:

```
NSNumber *cRating = [movie getRating:ratingDictionary ratingType:criticRating];
XCTAssertEqualObjects(cRating, [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:70], @"");
```

The error is:

```
[SFModelTest testGetCriticRatingMethod] failed: ((cRating) equal to ([[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:70])) failed: ("70") is not equal to ("70")
```

Since it is saying "70" is not equal to "70", I am guessing it has to do with alloc init. Some pointer stuff that is not equal. Can somebody please help? Thank you.

**Edit for comment: adding getRating method**

```
- (NSNumber *)getRating:(NSDictionary *)movieDic ratingType:(enum RatingsEnum) rating{

    NSNumber *result = 0;
    NSNumber *ratingNum = 0;

    switch (rating) {
        case userRating:
        {
            ratingNum = [movieDic objectForKey:@"audience_score"];
            break;
        }
        case criticRating:
        {
            ratingNum = [movieDic objectForKey:@"critics_score"];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

    if(ratingNum && ratingNum > 0)
    {
        result = ratingNum;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The method returns NSNumber. And my test is:

```
NSNumber *cRating = [movie getRating:ratingDictionary ratingType:criticRating];
XCTAssertEqualObjects(cRating, [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:70], @"");
```

When I do a class NSLOG, it returns __NSCFConstantString. I am confused now.

Comment: Within the `getRating:ratingType:` method, how are you creating the `NSNumber`?

Comment: NSNumber *result = 0; and then I return result at the end of the method.

Comment: try log the class of `cRating`. i.e. `NSLog(@"%@", [cRating class])` and sure it is not `NSString` or something else

Comment: What happens if you replace `[movie getRating:ratingDictionary ratingType:criticRating];` with just `[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:70]`?

Comment: class is __NSCFConstantString.

Comment: so your unit test is correct. `@"70"` (string) is different to `@70` (number)

Comment: Thanks @BryanChen, I understand that. I am not saying XCTest has a bug. I knew it was my code when I posted the question, but can you help figure out why? I am new to ObjectiveC. As far as I can tell, it is happening when I ask the dictionary for the value. Everything else is NSNUmber.

Comment: you should be able to track down the problem by yourself. hint: how did you create `ratingDictionary`

Comment: Thank you @BryanChen. So this is very interesting. I change the dictrionary to create value of NSNumber instead of @"70", which NSString and now the test passes. In my code, I am using NSDictionary *object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]; in the code to create it and that puts NSNumber and not NSString. Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're doing something wrong because `XCTAssertEqualObjects(@(1), @(1), @"Not equal.");` or `XCTAssertEqualObjects([NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"Not equal.");` if you are not familiar with literals, will pass.

You should checkout the `getRating:ratingType:` method to see which type of object it returns.

Try adding a breakpoint just before that `XCTAssertEqualObjects` and inspect the `cRating` instance.

Comment: I added more code. The problems seems to be casting the dictionary object to NSNumber. But I cannot pin it down.

Comment: The only way I could think of this to happen and you to be that sure that the values are correct is that the data from where the movieDic has it's values is in JSON format and you didn't unserialized it properly.